# C++ ntree Solid Tree Implementation

Tags: c++, tree

I know this kind of a question is asked before, especially in this website but I've seen hundreds of answers that just didn't fulfill my need. My apologies for asking such a generic question.

I need a tree implementation for a generating possible board states for a chess game that I'm implementing in C++. So here are the requirements:

- Only a single head node,
- Multiple (unknown number of) children nodes,
- Unknown (dynamic) height of the tree
- Tree will not be balanced, some branches may be cut off

Here is the data that I want to store:

```
// A tree's contents will only be composed of this variable
ChessModelConstants::ChessPiece m_gameBoard[8][8];

typedef char PieceType, PieceColor;

    //Variable is as follows
    struct ChessPiece {
    // A simple Constructor with default values
    ChessPiece(PieceType pieceType = ChessModelConstants::TYPE_EMPTY, 
               PieceColor pieceColor = ChessModelConstants::COLOR_WHITE) :
               m_pieceType(pieceType), m_pieceColor(pieceColor) 
    {
    }

    // Members
    PieceType m_pieceType;
    PieceColor m_pieceColor;
};
```

Where can I find / implement such a tree? I'd like to mention Boost is not an option for me currently. Any STL or a robust manual implementation would do fine. Thanks in advance.

PS: I've found [this](http://tree.phi-sci.com/documentation.html) website that I'm investigating currently.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer. Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, do you need something like this?

```
template<typename T>
class TreeItem
{
public:
    TreeItem<T> (T data)
        : m_data (data)
    {
    }

    TreeItem<T> (const TreeItem& item)
        : m_data (item.m_data)
    {
        m_children = item.m_children;
    }

    TreeItem<T>& AddChild (TreeItem<T>& item)
    {
        m_children.push_back (item);
        return *m_children.rbegin();
    }

    TreeItem<T>& AddChild (T data)
    {
        m_children.push_back (TreeItem<T>(data));
        return *m_children.rbegin();
    }

    std::vector<TreeItem<T> >& GetChildren ()
    {
        return m_children;
    }

    T& GetData()
    {
        return m_data;
    }

private:
    T m_data;
    std::vector<TreeItem<T> > m_children;
};

// usage example
ChessBoard emptyBoard;

TreeItem<ChessBoard> root (emptyBoard);
root.AddChild (emptyBoard).AddChild(emptyBoard);
```

Comment: Yeah I've implemented a quite similar structure myself.